# No change in algorithm performance following removal of important variable

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

performed a classification task with XGBoost where I aim to predict cardiovascular disease (CVD) with a dataset of 12 vars and 70 0000 data points and got an f1 score of 0.73.

After obtaining a feature plot the algorithm identified both weight and height as being important predictors for CVD.

However, when I remove either of these as features from the model there is no change in performance, despite them supposedly being of relatively high importance. There was low covariance between them (VIF<5). I can‘t think of an explanation for why dropping a high importance feature would not change model performance. Can anyone help?

Comment: By "no change" do you literally mean "no change", i.e., the *exactly* the same performance measure value? If this is the case, chances are you got something wrong, but nobody here can see what without knowing what exactly you did.

Comment: Valid question Christian, but no I mean very minor differnce. I know I coded correctly because it is as simple as adding 'weight' to the drop column

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how what is in the feature plot is computed, but I can imagine that weight and height are related to the remaining variables in such a way that their classification information can be taken over by potentially several of the other variables together. If classification information in the data is redundant, it can happen that taking out any single variable doesn't matter much, even though still some of them will show as "most important". This cannot always be detected looking just at correlations between pairs of variables.

Comment: I agree with this.  If you're interested in diagnosing this quantitatively, you can calculate the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) of your predictor variables.  Values over 10 for a predictor indicates that it has a high degree of multi-collinearity with the other predictors.  From the perspective of predictive modeling, this predictor is somewhat redundant.  From the perspective of descriptive modeling, it will be impossible to measure its isolated effect.

Comment: I know the VIF from multiple linear regression; corresponding issues in classifiers such as XGBoost that can model nonlinear structure cannot necessarily be spotted in this way, as they may also be caused by nonlinear dependencies.

Comment: I agree there may be specific cases of sophisticated nonlinear relationships that can not be identified with VIF, but VIF should be useful in most cases.  For example the relationship between weight, height, etc. will almost surely be comprehended by VIF.